# CUDA Compiler error. No input files specified;

Tags: c, compiler-construction, cuda

Trying to compile in win7 x64 cmd prompt. The following command:

```
nvcc -o kernal.cu
```

yields the following error message.

```
nvcc : fatal error : No input files specified; use option --help for more information
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

> nvcc -o xxx kernal.cu

where xxx is the output file name you want.